# Priority Queue ordering generates different result compared to Arrays.sort when using the same comparator

Tags: java

Priority Queue ordering generates different result compared to Arrays.sort when using the same comparator.
What changes should I make to the comparator for priority queue to give result similar to current Arrays.sort?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] logs = {"aa 1 2 3 4","hi small van","cc1 2 2","abc cat dog","i9 hat cat"};
    reorderLogs(logs);
}

public static String[] reorderLogs(String[] logs) {
    Comparator<String> myComp = new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            String[] s1 = o1.split(" ",2);
            String[] s2 = o2.split(" ",2);
            Boolean isDigit1 = Character.isDigit(s1[1].charAt(0));
            Boolean isDigit2 = Character.isDigit(s2[1].charAt(0));
            if(isDigit1 && isDigit2){
                return 0;
            }
            if(isDigit1){
                return 1;
            }
            if(isDigit2){
                return -1;
            }

            int x = s1[1].compareTo(s2[1]);
            if(x == 0){
                return s1[0].compareTo(s2[0]);
            }
            return x ;
        }
    };

    Queue<String> q = new PriorityQueue<>(myComp);
    q.addAll(Arrays.asList(logs));
    Arrays.sort(logs,myComp);
    String[] op = new String[q.size()];
    op = q.toArray(op);
    return op;
}
```